# preg_match() regex pattern to retrieve 3 things from my url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm a newbie in PHP regex patterns, so i tried to make a pattern for this URL:

```
$turl=http://ss-3.domian.com/screenshot/50/18/screenshot_multiple/501800/501800_multiple_1_extra_large.jpg
```

I just want to retrieve 3 things: "3", "50/18", "501800"

So I used this code:

```
preg_match('#http://ss-(.*?).domain.com/screenshot/(.*?)/screenshot_multiple/(.*?)/(.*?)_multiple_1_extra_large\.jpg#',$turl,$t_url)
```

So if I use `$matches[1]=3; $matches[2]=50/18; $matches[3]=501800`, I should get the numbers right??

Comment: Have you considered trying it, and seeing if it gives you what you want?

Comment: yeah, i have tried it but it gives an error :(

Comment: Then how come your question asks if it "shud" work? Are you asking if there's a bug in PHP? It seems more productive to state that it doesn't work, and to post the error message that you get.

Comment: No error given means no problem solved.

Comment: if you're working with regular expressions, then try regex coach. It will give you more feedback about your regex and why it's not matching certain strings. http://weitz.de/regex-coach/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$turl = 'http://ss-3.domain.com/screenshot/50/18/screenshot_multiple/501800/501800_multiple_1_extra_large.jpg';
preg_match_all('#http://ss\-([^\.]*)\.domain.com/[^/]+/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)#msi',$turl,$match);
// For testing
var_dump($match);
?>
```

You had a typo (domian) in the search string and it wasn't in quotes. This sort of URL is likely to change, so I've made it as generic as possible while still keeping the shape. I think if we knew your problem we would reconsider using regex if possible. Also, reading the function declarations in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is a big help and will give you a good understanding of their applications.